# Add large .rda file to a github package

Tags: r, github

Around two years ago, I wrote an R package with a dataset with all the reimbursements by Brazilian congresspeople from years 2009 to 2017. However, we are in 2019 and the .rda with my data has 103.7MB and github does not accept it anymore, since its limit is 100MB per file. Every time I upload my data files to my repository and try to reinstall my package from the internet, I get the same error:

```
devtools::install_github("mnunes/reembolsos")

## Downloading GitHub repo mnunes/reembolsos@master
##    checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
##    c/8hj8csfj73j4l4w93r1f0_vw0000gn/T/RtmpqJyGkK/remotes20e653cc012/mnunes-reembolsos-e5bdf6d/DESCRIPTION’ ...
## * installing *source* package ‘reembolsos’ ...
## ** using staged installation
## ** data
## *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
## Warning: file ‘camara.rda’ has magic number 'versi'
##   Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
## Error in load(zfile, envir = tmp_env) : 
##   bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
## ERROR: lazydata failed for package ‘reembolsos’
## * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/reembolsos’
## * restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/reembolsos’
## Error: Failed to install 'reembolsos' from GitHub:
##   (converted from warning) installation of package 
##     ‘/var/folders/gc/8hj8csfj73j4l4w93r1f0_vw0000gn/T//RtmpqJyGkK/file20e65765e06d/reembolsos_0.2.tar.gz’ 
##    had non-zero exit status
```

I do not have this problem if I install the package from my local computer, inside my own RStudio project.

I followed the instructions on https://git-lfs.github.com/, adapting them to .rda files, in order to make github store my large file, but I had no success.

How my problem can be solved?

Comment: I've recently been battling with this. Please try this: Update the `DESCRIPTION` such that `R (>= 3.4.3)` becomes `R (>= 3.6.1)`. Then rerun everything, upload and see if this makes a difference.

Comment: I tried installing your package. It worked, but I got this: `NB: this package now depends on R (>= 3.5.0)` `WARNING: Added dependency on R >= 3.5.0 because serialized objects in  serialize/load version 3 cannot be read in older versions of R.  File(s) containing such objects: 'reembolsos/data/camara.rda'`

Comment: Yeah, the package can be installed now because I removed three columns from the dataset. It doesn't have 103.7MB anymore, but only 96.3MB. I am still struggling with the large file problem, though.